# Algebraic Structure with Duality between Addition and Multiplication

Tags: abstract-algebra

As a layman, I suspect my question is ill-formed and I will do my best to explain what it is I mean.

I find the notion of algebraic structures absolutely fascinating. I understand that there exist structures that require certain properties of addition and multiplication to hold. As an example, a ring requires an abelian group with a second binary operation that is associative and distributes over the operation in the abelian group. A field is an example of another similar structure.

**The Question**

Given some set $A$ Is there a name for a structure $S$ that requires certain properties of $(A, +)$ and $(A, \cdot)$ to hold **that also** hold given $(A, \cdot)$ is the additive structure and $(A, +)$ the multiplicative structure? I am trying to say that it matters not which structure we consider as additive and multiplicative as the properties of the $S$ hold regardless. In this sense $(A, +)$ and $(A, \cdot)$ are dual to eachother. Do these objects exist and are they interesting to study?

My gut feeling says that I am failing to write my intent accurately and apologize in advance.

Comment: Are you referring to, for example, the fact that the real numbers $\mathbb R$ with respect to addition is isomorphic as groups to the positive real numbers $\mathbb R^+$ with respect to multiplication, the isomorphism being $x\mapsto e^x$.

Comment: Are you asking: does there exist a set $A$ and two binary operations $\oslash$ and $\odot$ so that $(A,\oslash,\odot)$ and $(A, \odot, \oslash)$ produce the same algebraic structure?

Comment: This is what I am asking Sloan. I think i could find some trivial examples however I wonder if there are interesting examples.

Comment: In particular, boolean algebras maybe? $(B,\vee,\wedge)\cong(B,\wedge,\vee)$

Answer (score 3):

As I understand it, you're looking for a set $A$ with two operations $\cdot$ and $+$ such that $(R, +, \cdot)$ is a ring *and* $(R, \cdot, +)$ is a ring.

Unfortunately, this can't really happen. It's not hard to show that in any ring, $0 \cdot r = 0$ for all $r \in R$. So $1 + r = 1$ for all $r \in R$ also, since $(R, \cdot, +)$ is a ring. But this implies $r = 0$ for all $r \in R$, so the only example is the trivial ring.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is interesting as it relates to rings but I am wondering what happens if we remove the requirements that the structure is a ring. Are there any interesting examples of structures that have $(A, +, \cdot) = (A, \cdot, +)$ in general, not necessarily a ring?

Answer (score 0):

One example that fits this sort of "swap the operations" requirement is a [lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order)#Lattices_as_algebraic_structures), though these two operations don't really behave like addition and multiplication. For these structures the operations are called join ($\vee$) and meet ($\wedge$) and are required to obey the following so-called absorption laws:

$a \vee (a \wedge b) = a$

$a \wedge (a \vee b) = a$

As you can see this is very much not a ring. Due to the symmetry of the definition, you'll note that if $(L,\vee,\wedge)$ is a lattice then $(L,\wedge,\vee)$ is also a lattice, though not necessarily the same one. Lattices essentially have one foot in abstract algebra and the other in order theory, and this duality is precisely the [duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_(order_theory)) of the corresponding posets. If a lattice is isomorphic to its dual it is called self-dual though this property is not shared by all lattices. Also the word "lattice" is used [elsewhere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(group)) in algebra to refer to something completely different, so you need to be carful which one is being discussed when reading.